# MySQL left join VERY slow, and usuall hangs forever

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables,  ticket_data and nps_data.

ticket_data hold general IT issue information and nps_data holds user feedback.
A basic idea of the tables are:

ticket_data table.
aprox. 1,500,000 rows: 30 fields:
Index on ticket_number, logged_date, logged_team, resolution_date

```
|ticket_number | logged_date | logged_team | resolution_date  |
| I00001       |  2017-01-01 | Help Desk   | 2017-01-02       |
| I00002       | 2017-02-01  | Help Desk   | 2017-03-01       |
| I00010       | 2017-03-04  | desktop sup | 2017-03-04       |
```

Obviously there are lots of other fields but this is what Im working with

nps_data table
aprox 83,000 rows: 10 fields:
index ticket_number

```
|ticket_number | resolving team| q1_score|
| I00001       | helpdesk      | 5       |
| I00002       | desktop sup   | 0       |
| I00010       | desktop sup   | 10      |
```

when I do a simple query such as

```
select a.*, b.q1_score from
(select * from ticket_data
where resolution_date > '2017-01-01') a
left join nps_data b
on a.ticket_number = b.ticket_number
```

The query takes forever to run, and when I say that, I mean I stop the query after 10 mins.
However if I run the query to join ticket_data with a table called ticket_details, which has over 1,000,000 rows using the following query

```
select *
(select * from ticket_data
where resolution_date > '2017-01-01') a
left join ticket_details b
on a.ticket_number = b.ticket_number
```

the query takes about 1.3 seconds to run.

Answer (score 0):

In the query above, you have a subquery with the alias `a` that is not running on an index. You are querying the field `resolution_date`, which is un-indexed.

The simple fix would be to add an index to that field.

Ticket number **is** indexed. This is probably why when you join on that, the query runs faster.

The other way to further optimize this would not to do `select *` in your subquery (which is bad practice in a production system anyway). It creates more overhead for the DBMS to pass all results up in the subquery.

Another way would be to do a partial index on the column such as:

`create index idx_tickets on ticket_data(ticket_number) where resolution_date > '2017-01-01'`

But I would only do that if the timestamp of '2017-01-01' is a constant that will always be used.

You could also create a composite index, so the query engine will run an `Index Only Scan` whereby it pulls the data straight from the index without having to go back to the table.

In order for me to reference something on this, I would need to know what DBMS you are running on.

Of course, all of this depends on what type of DBMS you are running.

Comment: Sorry resolution_date is indexed and running that sub query takes less than a second

Comment: What DBMS are you using? And have you done an EXPLAIN to look at the execution plan of the query?

Comment: You can also vacuum the table (if you are using Postgres) as it looks like your `nps_data` might have bloated dead rows in it, that the query planner is somehow trying to sift through.

Comment: I noticed that ticket_number on the nps_data had a character set latin1 where everywhere else its set to utf8.  I changed it to utf8 and its running under half a second